# Copy value from scope object in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive where I am reading in values as attributes and storing them in scope.  My markup is as follows:

```
<my-directive
        ng-model="myCtrl.widgets"
        widget-amount="myCtrl.widgets"
        sprocket-amount="myCtrl.sprockets">
</my-directive>
```

and my directive is defined like:

```
        return {
            scope: {
                widgetAmount                : '=',
                sprocketAmount              : '=',
                ....
```

The directive then allows the user to modify the widget amount.

The problem I'm having is that in my directive code, I want to do some calculations with the ORIGINAL value of the widget amount, but I can't seem to save off that value.  I have tried `angular.copy` to no avail.  It seems to be simply returning me a copy that is also changing along with the value in the directive.  How can I just grab the original value of this variable while at the same time preserving the two-way binding?

Comment: `angular.copy` will retain any special angular values such as `$$hashKey` - which will act as a pointer back to the original variable. You can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(variable));` to clone it without those values or use `_.clone` if you're using underscore.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I am interpreting this correctly.

## Use Case

Retain original value of a two-direction bounded value within a directive.

### Solution

You can use a directive's controller to retain that value.

### Code

```
function myDirective() {
    return {
        scope: {
            widgetAmount: '=',
            sprocketAmount: '='
        },
        ...
        controller: function($scope) {
            // Retain the original value
            $scope.original = $scope.widgetAmount;

            // Modify the widgetAmount
            $scope.widgetAmount *= 2;
        }
    };
};
```

### Example

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a2kj5/)

#### HTML Template

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <my-directive
            ng-model="myCtrl.widgets"
            widget-amount="myCtrl.widgets"
            sprocket-amount="myCtrl.sprockets">
        </my-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Angular Code

```
angular.module('app', [])
       .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.myCtrl = {
        widgets : 5,
        sprockets : 10
    }
}

function myDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            widgetAmount: '=',
            sprocketAmount: '='
        },
        template: '<pre>{{ original }} {{ widgetAmount }} {{ sprocketAmount }}</pre>',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.original = $scope.widgetAmount;

            $scope.widgetAmount *= 2;
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Yep, you are interpreting it correctly.  Your answer doesn't work for me, BUT it did lead me to the correct way to do this.  I am using a compile and post function in my directive, so the controller part was a bit hairy.  Your answer though led me to think that I should be saving off the value in another phase or at least earlier up in my code, so thank you.